Register using both BasedOn and a second interface
I register a number of classes using this syntax:
container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).BasedOn<IFoo>()
.WithService.Base().LifestyleSingleton());

One of these classes implements a second interface, call it 'IBar', which I need to inject elsewhere. If I try to register that class against this interface using the following then Windsor complains that the class is already registered:
container.Register(Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>().LifeStyle.Singleton);

Adding .Named("...") allows the registration to proceed, but resolving IBar obviously gives me a second singleton instance of MyClass, when I actually need the same singleton instance as the earlier .BasedOn() registration.
Can this be done?
